# Prove or disprove the following statement: if $A,B$ are sets, then $\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)=\wp(A\cup B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove or disprove the following statement.

> If $A,B$ are sets, then $\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)=\wp(A\cup B)$.

Instead of using a counter-example, I decided to disprove the statement: if $A,B$ are sets, then $\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)=\wp(A\cup B)$.

This is my thought process:

Let $X$ be a set and $X\in\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)$, we know that $X\subseteq A\cup B$. But if $X\subseteq A\cup B$, $X\in\wp(A)\cup\wp(B)$ does not necessarily hold.

Comment: What does P mean here?

Comment: $X \subseteq A \cup B \implies X \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$ is true, because $X \subseteq Y \iff X \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$ is the meaning of $\mathcal{P}$. It's the other way that doesn't work. And "does not necessarily hold" statements can really only be proved with a counterexample.

Comment: P means powerset

Comment: @MengenLiu, actually $\wp$ does mean “power set”.

Comment: That is not a proof. It is just an assertion that the theorem is true.

Comment: "Does not necessarily hold" is just another way of saying "there is a counterexample". But you still have to provide one, not just assert that one exists.

Comment: @Angelo $P$ is also used for power set.

Comment: @JohnDouma, you could use $\;\mathcal P(A)\;,\;\mathscr P(A)\;,\;\wp(A)\;,\;2^A\;$ but $\;P(A)$ is not appropriate because it could mean many other things.

Comment: @Angelo Or I could just use $P$. Please stop editing my post.

Comment: @JohnDouma, if David asked what $P$ means, there is a reason.

Comment: @Angelo And it was clarified by Mengen. This is the nature of mathematics. We could use the letter $Q$ as long as we explain what we mean. For me, it was obvious what was meant because of the context.

Comment: @JohnDouma, indirectly you admited that $P$ is not the appropriate symbol for power set, indeed Mengen needed to clarify its meaning and you understood it because of the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X\subseteq A\cup B$ then, by definition $X\in P(A\cup B)$.

Let $A=\{a,b\}$ and let $B=\{1,2\}$.

Then $X=\{a,1\}\in P(A\cup B)$ but is in neither $P(A)$ nor $P(B)$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks

Comment: @Angelo Please stop editing my post. I used $P$ because it is a commonly used symbol for the power set.

Comment: @JohnDouma, you could use $\;\mathcal P(A)\;,\;\mathscr P(A)\;,\;\wp(A)\;,\;2^A\;$ but $\;P(A)$ is not appropriate because it could mean many other things.

Comment: Or I could just use $P$. There is no preferred notation for this.

Comment: @JohnDouma, if David have asked what $P$ means, there is a reason. If OP had used $\wp$, he would not have asked it.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of pursuing OP’s stated line of thought, here is an argument that doesn’t proceed via counterexample. Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint sets with $n\geq 2$ elements each. Then $\wp(A)$ has $2^n$ elements, $\wp(B)$ has $2^n$ elements, and $\wp(A) \cup \wp(B)$ has $2^n + 2^n - 1 = 2^{n+1}-1$ elements; but $\wp(A\cup B)$ has $2^{2n}$ elements…and when $n \ge 2$ we have $2^{2n} \gt 2^{n+ 1} \gt 2^{n+ 1}- 1$. So we cannot have $\wp(A)\cup \wp(B) = \wp(A\cup B)$ in general.